# Flipping OpenGL ES Texture Obtained Through CVOpenGLESTexture

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

In the past day of my foray into OpenGL ES 2.0, while attempting to apply two projective textures -- one sprite animation and one video file texture -- to a skybox, I started simply pounding my hands on the keyboard like stubs, and miraculously it all started working.

However, the texture created from the video file is flipped upside-down. In other words, the texture coordinates for (0,0) seem to be mapping to (0,1), and vice-versa.

The function which creates the video file texture from a CVImageBufferRef, CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(), includes a parameter "CFDictionaryRef textureAttributes."

CVOpenGLESTextureCache.h helpfully explains: "A CFDictionaryRef containing attributes to be used for creating the CVOpenGLESTexture objects.  May be NULL."

I immediately thought of GLKTextureLoader, which allows you to pass in an options dictionary, with one of the available options being used to flip the texture around.

So, I'm a bit confused on two points:

1. Will passing in a CFDictionaryRef of attributes allow me to easily change things about the texture, like rotation? Or does it somehow mean 'attribute' in the shader-sense? (I don't think it very likely means the shader-sense, but I also think it's odd that it calls them attributes and not options.)
2. Is there a list somewhere of the key/value pairs that will tell it to do useful things?

I wanted to look into this before finding some other way to flip it around, since if it's possible to do it here, it seems like it would be the most straightforward way, if the procedure is indeed parallel to GLKTextureLoader's options.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through apple's RosyWriter sample code again, I've realized that after creating the texture with CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(), they flip the texture around by modifying the texture coordinates for the vertices.

Since I'm projecting the texture and computing the texture coordinates in the vertex shader, I think the simplest solution for me will be to flip the actual movie file asset around before I drop it into xcode. So that's probably what I'll do for each movie. Just realized what a simple solution that is. That way I don't need to fork my vertex shader code for projections that need to be rotated & don't need to be rotated.

I'd still really appreciate clarification on the attributes argument though, if anybody has info on that.

Comment: Regarding the attributes, I've never used them as anything other than NULL. If you look near the top of the header, you see `// textureAttributes - reserved for future use `. Can't remember if they added anything to this for iOS 6.0.