# Why would an OpenGL ES render on iOS be flipped vertically?

Tags: android, ios, c, opengl-es

I've got some C code to render some OpenGL stuff and it's running on both Android and iOS. On Android it looks fine. But on iOS it is flipped vertically.

Here's some simple code to demonstrate (only copied the relevant parts because OpenGL C code is long-winded):

```
GLfloat vVertices[] = {
    0.0f,  0.5f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f
};

glViewport(0, 0, context->width, context->height);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(data->programObject);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

On Android it looks like this:

[image]

But on iOS it looks like this:

[image]

The only thing that differs between the two platforms is the initialization code for OpenGL ES, since all the OpenGL code is shared C code. However, I can't spot anything obviously wrong with the init code.

Here's the init code (I removed most error handling because there are no errors being triggered apart from the one I left in):

```
- (void)initGL {
    _context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3];

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];
    [self createCVBufferWithSize:_renderSize withRenderTarget:&_target withTextureOut:&_texture];

    glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(_texture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_texture));

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,         // target
                 0,                     // level
                 GL_RGBA,               // internalformat
                 _renderSize.width,     // width
                 _renderSize.height,    // height
                 0,                     // border
                 GL_RGBA,               // format
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,      // type
                 NULL);                 // data
    // HACK: we always get an "error" here (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) despite everything working. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57104033/why-is-glteximage2d-returning-gl-invalid-operation-on-ios
    glGetError();

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_depthBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, _renderSize.width, _renderSize.height);
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &_frameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBuffer);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_texture), 0);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthBuffer);

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Successfully initialized GL");
        char* glRendererName = getGlRendererName();
        char* glVersion = getGlVersion();
        char* glShadingLanguageVersion = getGlShadingLanguageVersion();

        NSLog(@"OpenGL renderer name: %s, version: %s, shading language version: %s", glRendererName, glVersion, glShadingLanguageVersion);
    }
}
```

And here's the code that creates the actual texture (using EAGL):

```
- (void)createCVBufferWithSize:(CGSize)size
              withRenderTarget:(CVPixelBufferRef *)target
                withTextureOut:(CVOpenGLESTextureRef *)texture {

    CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, _context, NULL, &_textureCache);

    if (err) return;

    CFDictionaryRef empty;
    CFMutableDictionaryRef attrs;
    empty = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                               NULL,
                               NULL,
                               0,
                               &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                               &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    attrs = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 1,
                                      &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                      &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    CFDictionarySetValue(attrs, kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey, empty);
    CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, size.width, size.height,
                        kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, attrs, target);

    CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                 _textureCache,
                                                 *target,
                                                 NULL, // texture attributes
                                                 GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                 GL_RGBA, // opengl format
                                                 size.width,
                                                 size.height,
                                                 GL_BGRA, // native iOS format
                                                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                 0,
                                                 texture);

    CFRelease(empty);
    CFRelease(attrs);
}
```

Can anyone tell me why iOS is flipped like this? I've since noticed other people with the same problem, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588350/flipping-opengl-es-texture-obtained-through-cvopenglestexture) but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: "Basically, y = 0 on Android is at the top of the screen, whereas y = 0 on iOS is at the bottom." Both should be on center. And both should be `-1` at bottom, `1` at top. Also from images you have posted the Android one seems correct as you have 2 vertices with `y = -0.5` and android shows 2 points at the bottom. I expect either you are using some matrix or there is some setting enabled to flip the layer vertically on iOS. From the setup also it might be you are incorrectly using the FBO which flips it but more information would be needed as to what you are doing here.

Comment: Oops, yeah I was thinking in a different coordinate space when I wrote that. I'll remove it from my question. What more information would help determine whether the FBO is being flipped?

Comment: The code you posted from initialization only seems to be about some FBO which has attached a texture as a color buffer and a new render buffer for depth. But how is this then drawn to your main buffer? Do you maybe redraw this texture and flip it there? Or do you use some high level tools from GLKit which could be responsible for that like GLKView?

Comment: @MaticOblak Sorry for the slow response. I've just updated my question with the texture init code. Turns out, other people have this problem as well, and I included one such link in my question. Haven't found a solution yet.